# MySQL Delete all rows with a certain variable

Tags: mysql

So I run a product, but accounts expire and use up database space. How would I delete all accounts that have the 'paid' value set to 0? (The value gets set to 0 when the account expires).

Thank you!

Comment: Rather than setting the value to 0 when the account expires, why not delete the account (if that's really what you want to do... generally speaking, in my experience it is better to leave disabled entries hanging around for auditing/recovery purposes).

Answer (score 1):

`delete from table where paid=0;`

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE paid=0
```

Answer (score 0):

What if the **paid column** has a `NULL` value, i think you would like to read it as **0**

hence the `Query`

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE COALESCE(paid,0)=0
```

**[Working wit NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)**